# How to send correct data types using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want send correct data types to server using ajax, I mean, I want server received boolean as boolean, integer as integer (not string) and so on...

I tried this, but server receives empty array when I check `$_POST`.

```
params = {"firts_step":true};

$.ajax({

    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "url_here",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    success: function(msg){


    }
});
```

if try this:

```
params = {"firts_step":true};

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "url_here",
    data: params,
    success: function(msg){


    }
});
```

then there is data in `$_POST` array, though all values have string data type.

Comment: All query strings are strings.  If you want to send JSON to php, iirc, you have to read it off the body and parse it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you add two `data` objects to the ajax call. Remove the one without `json.stringify` and try this from the php side,

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data["firts_step"];
```

Comment: two data objects was just typo. I edited question, and this works fine, thank you.

Comment: @RIKI Glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

If you select JSON as your content type, you will only be able to send data with the types specified by the [JSON documentation](https://www.json.org/). Also, before parsing your JSON make sure your object has the correct data types.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTP is a text protocol with no concept of booleans or integers everything must be stringified

for booleans test this

```
params = {"firts_step":true ? 1 : 0};
```

and in php

```
$x = ($_POST['firts_step'] == 1 ) ? true : false;
```

or

```
params {"firts_step":"TRUE" };
```

and in php

```
$x = ($_POST['firts_step'] == "TRUE" ) ? true : false;
```

good luck

Answer (score -1):

In php for boolean you can use the filter_var

example:

```
$params['first_step'] = filter_var( $params['first_step'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

here the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php